# Import multiple file .blst (look like .csv) to excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to import multiple file .blst into one worksheet and want to place .blst files horizontally in a worksheet. Which one file will place separate about 23 column such as first file place in column A1 - W1 and second X1- AT1 continue ...n file. But my code cannot open them.

This below code is Convert to Letter function

```
Function ConvertToLetter(iCol As Integer) As String
   Dim iAlpha As Integer
   Dim iRemainder As Integer
   iAlpha = Int(iCol / 27)
   iRemainder = iCol - (iAlpha * 26)
   If iAlpha > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = Chr(iAlpha + 64)
   End If
   If iRemainder > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = ConvertToLetter & Chr(iRemainder + 64)
   End If
   Debug.Print ConvertToLetter & 1
End Function
```

This below code is  import wizard function

```
Function import_wizard(xFileName, xAddress) As String

   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & xFileName, Range(xAddress))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 936
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ";"
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With


End Function
```

This below code is button to browse and import multi file .blst

```
Private Sub browseXML_Click()

    Dim xFileName As Variant
    Dim xAddress As String
    Dim countFile As Integer


    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    xFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="blst Files,*.*", Title:="Select file", MultiSelect:=True)

    If IsArray(xFileName) Then
            'Msg = vbNewLine
        For i = LBound(xFileName) To UBound(xFileName)
            Msg = Msg & xFileName(i) & vbCrLf
            countFile = i + 23

            xAddress = ConvertToLetter(countFile) & "1"
            SplitterMark.TextBox1.Value = Msg
            Call import_wizard(xFileName, xAddress)

        'Debug.Print "X = " & xAddress
        Next i

    Else
        MsgBox "No files were selected."
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If

ExitHandler:
ErrHandler:
End Sub
```

When i tired to comment `' Call import_wizard(xFileName, xAddress)` the code can select multi file and can show on UI, but tired to delete comment `Call import_wizard(xFileName, xAddress)` can select multi file but it is show only last file from select and not open them file. I not sure it not do  `ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & xFileName, Range(xAddress))` or not. Could someone please to suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the "(i)" to select each individual file in this code row:

```
Call import_wizard(xFileName(i), ...
```

You don't need your "ConvertToLetter" function to convert a column number to the address.
I suggest to calculate the next import column like this:

```
...
Dim NextColumn As Long
For i = LBound(xFileName) To UBound(xFileName)
    NextColumn = (i - 1) * 23 + 1
    Call import_wizard(xFileName(i), NextColumn)
Next i
...
```

Your import routine then has to start like this:

```
Function import_wizard(ByVal xFileName as String, NextColumn as Long) As String
   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & xFileName, ActiveSheet.Cells(1, NextColumn))
       ...
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I tired correct per you suggest. but in `Call import_wizard(xFileName(i), NextColumn)`  it is show some error about `ByRef argument type mismatch`  How i do that ?

Comment: Oh, i got it. Thank you very much